# My code is writing to a file wrong using fseek()

Tags: c

So i'm trying to write to a file line based on a variable called index which is basically the line number of the file. For some reason the fseek function is not working. It works for index=0 but not for index=1 and so on. The variable extra is not getting put into the file at the right place. I have put index*13 in fseek as there are 11 spaces after each zero in the outstanding file. I have tried index*12 even.
The take loan function of my code does this part. please ignore what I have commented out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct account{
    char name[20];
    char accnum[9];
    int balance;
    long outstanding;
    int flag;
    char pin[5];
};
int difference(int d2,int m2,int y2){
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    struct tm d = { 0 }, dd = { 0 };
    dd.tm_year = tm.tm_year ; 
    dd.tm_mon = tm.tm_mon+1;
    dd.tm_mday = tm.tm_mday;
    d.tm_year = y2 - 1900;
    d.tm_mon = m2;
    d.tm_mday = d2;
    return(difftime(mktime(&dd), mktime(&d)))/(24*3600);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void takeloan(FILE *atm,FILE *outstanding,struct account holders[],int index,int extra){
    FILE *loandates;
    char daystr[2],monthstr[2],yearstr[4],ch;
    long day,month,year;
    int i,count=0,dashcount=0,entercount=0,count1=0,j,k;

    loandates=fopen("loandates.txt","r+");
    for(j=0;j<15;j++){
        for(k=0;k<2;k++){
            ch=fgetc(loandates);
            daystr[k]=ch;
        }
        for(k=0;k<2;k++){
            ch=fgetc(loandates);
            monthstr[k]=ch;
        }
        for(k=0;k<4;k++){
            ch=fgetc(loandates);
            yearstr[k]=ch;
        }
        if(j==index){
            break;
        }
        fseek(loandates,(j+1)*9,SEEK_SET);      
    }

//  puts(daystr);
//  puts(monthstr);
//  puts(yearstr);
    char *ptr;
    char temp[13];
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    day = strtol(daystr, &ptr, 10);
    month = strtol(monthstr, &ptr, 10);
    year = strtol(yearstr, &ptr, 10);
  //    printf("%d", day);
  //    printf("%d", month);
  //    printf("%d", year);
    if(holders[index].flag==1){
        float y=difference(day,month,year);
        if(y<=20){
            printf("Please pay back the loan you have already taken.\n");
          }
          else{
            printf("Your account is banned as you have crossed the deadline for paying back the loan. Please contact the bank for further details. ");
          }
      }
    else{
        atm=fopen("atm.txt","r+");
        for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
            ch=fgetc(atm);
            count++;
            if(ch=='-'){
                dashcount++;
            }
            if(dashcount==(index+1)*2){
                break;
            }   
        }
        fseek(atm,count+(dashcount/2)-1,SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(atm,"1");

        holders[index].outstanding=extra;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        outstanding=fopen("outstanding.txt","r+");
        fseek(outstanding,index*13,SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(outstanding,"%d",extra);
        fclose(outstanding);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        fseek(loandates,index*9,SEEK_SET);  
        if(tm.tm_mday>=0&&tm.tm_mday<=9){
            fprintf(loandates,"%d ",tm.tm_mday);
        }
        else{
            fprintf(loandates,"%d",tm.tm_mday);
        }
        if(tm.tm_mon>=0&&tm.tm_mon<=9){
            fprintf(loandates,"%d ",tm.tm_mon+1);
        }
        else{
            fprintf(loandates,"%d",tm.tm_mon+1);
        }
        fprintf(loandates,"%d",tm.tm_year+1900);            
        }



    fclose(loandates);
    fclose(atm);



}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(){
    char Cpin[4],Caccnum[8];
    char ch,outstandingstr[9000];
    int p,test;
    char *ptr;
    for(p=0;p<9000;p++){
        outstandingstr[p]=' ';  
    }
    int i,j;
    FILE *atm,*outstanding,*pins,*balance;
    atm=fopen("atm.txt","r");
    outstanding=fopen("outstanding.txt","r");
    pins=fopen("pins.txt","r");
    balance=fopen("balance.txt","r");
    struct account holders[15];
    for(i=0;i<15;i++){
        for(j=0;j<30;j++){
            ch=fgetc(atm);
            holders[i].name[j]=ch;
            if(ch=='-'){
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<20;j++){
            if(!((holders[i].name[j]>='A'&&holders[i].name[j]<='Z')||(holders[i].name[j]>='a'&&holders[i].name[j]<='z')||(holders[i].name[j]==' '))){
                holders[i].name[j]='\0';        
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<30;j++){
            ch=fgetc(atm);
            holders[i].accnum[j]=ch;
            if(ch=='-'){
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<9;j++){
            if(!(holders[i].accnum[j]>='0'&&holders[i].accnum[j]<='9')){
                holders[i].accnum[j]='\0';
            }       
        }
        ch=fgetc(atm);
        int x = ch - '0';
        holders[i].flag=x;
        fseek(atm,2,SEEK_CUR);
        fscanf(balance,"%d",&holders[i].balance);
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            ch=fgetc(pins);
            holders[i].pin[j]=ch;       
        }
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
                if(!(holders[i].pin[j]>='0'&&holders[i].pin[j]<='9')){
                holders[i].pin[j]='\0';
            }
        }

        fseek(pins,(i+1)*6,SEEK_SET);

        fgets(outstandingstr,13,outstanding);



        holders[i].outstanding = strtol(outstandingstr, &ptr, 10);

        for(p=0;p<9000;p++){
            outstandingstr[p]=' ';  
        }
    //  fseek(outstanding,2)

    }
    fclose(pins);
    fclose(outstanding);
    fclose(balance);
    fclose(atm);
    printf("Enter account number: ");
    gets(Caccnum);
    int index=0;
    while(1){
        if(strcmp(Caccnum,holders[index].accnum)==0){
            break;
        }
        else{
            index++;
        }   
    }
    printf("%d",index);
    puts(holders[index].pin);
    printf("Enter pin: ");
    gets(Cpin);
    while(strcmp(Cpin,holders[index].pin)!=0){
        printf("Wrong pin. Enter Again: ");
        gets(Cpin);
    } 
    //puts(holders[index].name);
//  puts(holders[index].accnum);
//  printf("%d",holders[13].outstanding);
//  printf("\n\n");
    takeloan(atm,outstanding,holders,index,785);


}
```

File outstanding:
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>
0<11 spaces>

Comment: Your code uses `gets()`.  Never use gets.  In addition, the argument you pass has size 4.  My guess is this is overwriting something and invoking UB.  NEVER USE `gets()`

Comment: what s an alternative to gets? also which argument has a size of 4?

Comment: You seem to be using a text file with random access, which is usually not the way to do it. Random access with `fseek` works best on a structured file with fixed length records. But your text records are of variable length, and if you overwrite `10000` with `9999` then the file contains `99990`. Unlike a structured file, a text file does not contain `nul` string terminators, and you don't seem to justify the widths or blank out previous data. With a text file, it is usual to read the entire file into memory structures, make changes, and write the entire data back to a text file.

Comment: ... here is one such example: `fseek(outstanding,index*13,SEEK_SET); fprintf(outstanding,"%d",extra);` At the very least, you should write a fixed width field, such as `"%10d"`.

Comment: `fgets` is a reasonable alternative.  The `Cpin` array has size 4.  SInce you are reading a pin into it, you probably expect to read a string of length 5 (include the newline) and `gets` is trying to put 6 characters into that array (4 digits of pin plus newline plust a null terminator.  That's in the best case scenario where the input is what you expect.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: It looks like `gets` does not actually store the newline as `fgets` does.  However, since it has been removed from the language and should never be used, this is not an important piece of information.  Merely historical trivia.

Comment: yes I'm running this on windows

Answer (score 0):

You disregarded this paragraph in the C standard, section **The fseek function**:

> For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by
>   an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function …

Since you want to use a computed `offset`, you must not use a *text stream*; in order to use a *binary stream*, you have to include `b` in the `fopen` `mode`. Be aware that you can't necessarily process files that have previously been written as a *text stream* later by opening them as a *binary stream*.